# Update con SQLServer DataSnap y Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-2010

Estimados tengo un problema al queres actualizar con SqlServer. Estoy desarrollando un programa con un servidor DataSnap y tengo este problema cuando quiero actualizar un campo en el DBGrid.

**Se que el error esta en el campo clave de la consulta sql o mas bien, es el campo clave que pertenece a la base de datos (campo: codigo).**

No se como desarrollar la consulta sql con delphi y que no me genere ese problema con mi campo clave código.

```
State 01000, SQL Error Code 3621
State 23000, SQL Error Code 2627
```

Codigo del lado del servidor:

```
function TTServerMethods.updateItems(cod: String; desc: string; const pre:Integer): String;
begin
 try
       if not EjemploDatasnap.Connected then
          EjemploDatasnap.Connected := true;


       if SQLDataSetUpdateItems.Active then
          SQLDataSetUpdateItems.Active := False;

       SQLDataSetUpdateItems.ParamByName('codigops').AsString := cod;
       SQLDataSetUpdateItems.ParamByName('descripcion').AsString := desc;
       SQLDataSetUpdateItems.ParamByName('precio').AsInteger := pre;
       SQLDataSetUpdateItems.ExecSQL;
       SQLDataSetUpdateItems.Active := True;
       //SQLDataSetIProductos.Active:=False;



   except on
   E: Exception do
    Result := E.Message;
 end;
end;
```

Codigo del SQLDataSet:

```
object SQLDataSetUpdateItems: TSQLDataSet
    SchemaName = 'JDario'
    CommandText = 
      'UPDATE productos SET Descripcion = :descripcion, Precio = :preci' +
      'o   WHERE   codigo = :codigops'
    MaxBlobSize = -1
    Params = <
      item
        DataType = ftString
        Name = 'descripcion'
        ParamType = ptInput
      end
      item
        DataType = ftInteger
        Name = 'precio'
        ParamType = ptInput
      end
      item
        DataType = ftString
        Name = 'codigops'
        ParamType = ptInput
      end>
    SQLConnection = EjemploDataSnap
    Left = 40
    Top = 280
  end
```

Codigo del lado del cliente:

```
procedure TForm5.aceptarEdicionClick(Sender: TObject);
var client : TTServerMethodsClient;
var ds:TDataset;
var codigo : STring;
var Descripcion : STring;
var Precio : Integer;
begin
client :=   TTServerMethodsClient.Create(SQLConProductosGrid.DBXConnection);

begin

  ds := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet;

     if not SQLConProductosGrid.Connected  then
            SQLConProductosGrid.Connected := True;


    DBGrid1.SetFocus;


    codigo := ds.FieldByName('codigo').AsString;
    Descripcion := ds.FieldByName('Descripcion').AsString;
    Precio := ds.FieldByName('Precio').AsInteger;

    Label3.Caption := client.updateItems(codigo,Descripcion,Precio);
    ds.UpdateRecord;
    ds.Next;

end;
```

Comment: Hay un mensaje de error?

Answer (score -1):

Si, pero ya esta solucionado. Me quedaba solo abrir y cerrar la conexión antes y después de la consulta:

```
SqlDataSet.Open;
Query.....
SqlDataSet.Close;
```